# how to show the result in omnet++ in specific round?

Tags: nodes, categories, omnet++, wireless

I simulate a wireless sensor network in omnet++ (mixim),i want to analys the result in specific round like 500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500 and 4000. i write the code as follow,but it dose not work and show the result in some rounds like 496,492 and 502.how could i change the code to show that specific 7 round that i mentioned?
the code:

```
 int rr;
    rr=static_cast<SensorNode *>(this->getParentModule()->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("node",1)->getSubmodule("netwl"))->GetRound();

    if(abs(rr-500)<5 || abs(rr-1000)<5 || abs(rr-1500)<5 || abs(rr-2000)<5 || abs(rr-2500)<5 || abs(rr-3000)<5 || abs(rr-35000)<5 || abs(rr-4000)<5)
    {
            char ss1[30];
            sprintf(ss1,"Dead_CHs_Round_%d",rr);
            recordScalar(ss1,nDeadCH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks if the difference between `rr` and your expected rounds is smaller than 5. For example

```
rr = 496
if ( abs(rr-500) < 5 || .....) {
    // your code
}
//--> abs(496 - 500) < 5 
//--> abs(-4) < 5 
//-->  4 < 5 --> true
```

So your if clause becomes true for `rr = 496`.
To avoid this, remove the `abs()` and the `<5` and change it like following:

```
if( rr == 500 || rr == 1000 || .....) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question,I'd changed the code but at the result it dosen't show the whole rounds that i want,it only shows the result of round 1000,2500,and 4000, what shuld i write to show the other round?

Comment: I slightly edited my answer.
Can you post your if statement? So I can take a look on it.

Comment: int rr;
        rr=static_cast<SensorNode *>(this->getParentModule()->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("node",1)->getSubmodule("netwl"))->GetRound();

        if(rr==500 || rr==1000 || rr==1500 || rr==2000 || rr==2500 || rr==3000 || rr==3500 || rr==4000)

Comment: Are you sure that `rr` becomes 500? This if statement should work I think..

Comment: I'd write this part at line123 at "bs.cc" file.     "rr" should have to count in spite of "GetRound()"function that refer to Round count at the file "sensorNode.cc"
I inserted the whole code at the following link:                                                  https://ufile.io/3ff83